# CMFCShellTreeCtrl not displaying icons

Tags: c++, mfc, treeview

I am programming with C++ and MFC.

I have a CMFCShellTreeCtrl as one of the child windows in my application. It is created like this:

```
const DWORD dwViewStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TVS_HASLINES | TVS_LINESATROOT | TVS_HASBUTTONS;

m_wndFileView.Create(dwViewStyle, rectDummy, this, 4))
```

It displays correctly, but doesn't show any icons for the files. Just blank spaces where icons for folders/files should be. I looked at the function `SHGetImageList`, it could be my solution to get an appropriate image list and supply it to the Tree control, but I'm having trouble doing the conversion. The image list returned are of type IImageList, but I need CImageList.

Is there a way to convert between these two? Or is there a simple function to make the CMFCShellTreeCtrl show icons that I missed?

Any help would be appreciated.